# split text file with lines into mutiple lines by nth numbers

Tags: python-3.x, list

I am trying make script that split text file with lines into multiple lines group in python3
here is an example:

text file contains:

1

2

3

4

5

6

7

8

9

10

output that I want:

first chunk

1

2

3

second chunk

4

5

6

third chunk

7

8

9

fourth chunk

10

how can I do that? and thank you in advance

Comment: Do you need it to literally say `first`, `second`, etc? Or can it be `1. chunk`, `2. chunk`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @alex I want just put it in variable no needs for name

Comment: You want the output in variables (what types)? Or in files? Please make your question *clear*.

Comment: @alex list type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def divide_chunks(l, n):
    for i in range(0, len(l), n): 
        yield l[i:i + n]

with open(path_to_txt_file) as f:
    arr = f.read().splitlines()

divide_chunks(arr, 3)
```

which gives (as generator):

```
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9'], ['10']]
```